# findBy not working for microseconds in Instant with Postgres timestamp

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I'm finding an entity on the basis of `java.time.Instant` from PostgreSQL database using findBy method of jpa(ex. findByDateOfOrder).
But findBy is not able to find out desired entity when `Instant` have microseconds level precision.

Ex: not working for 2018-02-16T17:19:41.999999Z but works for 
2018-02-16T17:19:41.999Z

Comment: can you show your repository class with method

Comment: What is the type of the column in table? What precision does it have?

Comment: kindly define how "Instant" field is persisted. `AttributeConverter`? In which case, post the converter ...

Comment: @pvpkiran 
`import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import java.time.Instant;
import java.util.UUID;

public interface SampleJpaRepository extends JpaRepository<Sample, UUID> {

    public Sample findByDatePeriod(Instant datePeriod);
}`

Comment: @RomanPuchkovskiy In database(postgres) type of column is timestamp with time zone and precision is microsecond.

Comment: @DN1 `Instant` field is persisted as it is i.e. without using any `AttributeConverter`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was with Java version. We are using Java 8 and thus JPA didn't able to understand microsecond precision. And with advent of Java 9, by default precision is set to microseconds in an Instant.